# Can't enter Apple Hardware Test Mode on my macbook pro

Tags: startup, memory, apple-hardware-test

I have an Early 2011 MacBook Pro.  When I hold down D immediately after restart, it boots to the normal login screen.
When I hold down ALT+D (with a working wifi connection before the reboot) the same thing happens.

I'm running macOS 10.13.5

I don't have an original Applications Install disc 2 as mentioned [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201257).

Any ideas why I can't enter AHT mode? I'm trying to troubleshoot an intermittent fault where the mac won't boot, gives me 3 beeps on a black screen (suspect faulty RAM, but want to run AHT first to check).

Recovery mode works correctly, but doesn't give the option to enter AHT mode.

Comment: Can you try Ethernet? I find Wi-Fi is a bit finicky, even with newer models, when dealing with AHT.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following terminal commands to determine the model and board ID of your computer:

```
sysctl hw.model | awk '{ print $2 }'
ioreg -l | awk -F\" '/board-id/ { print $4 }'
```

Then download the proper AHT from this link

https://github.com/upekkha/AppleHardwareTest